# How to get an old ISO of a game to play music from the CD-ROM when the CD is not inserted

Tags: iso-image, music, extract

As a kid, I got a free racing ad-game on CD-ROM, from the same company who made Mall Maniacs. As the disc's becoming 20 years old, and the publisher went bust in 2003, it felt mandatory to make an ISO (or well, DAA as in PowerISO), to keep accessing it whenever the CD decides to die. The game is nowhere to be found on the internet anymore.

The ISO, however, doesn't contain (or at least won't play) the CD-ROM's in-game music. The only way to play the music is with the CD in the drive, and with that drive first in order. Is there any way to get around this, instead of burning another CD?

Comment: I believe (I could be wrong) there are means of "paritioning" an optical disk to allow CD audio and data to be stored seperately on the same disk. Unless you took care to make an exact image of the entire disk, your ISO may not have the CD audio portions of the original disk. Or, are you saying that if you burn the ISO to a disk you can play the CD audio? If that's the case please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: Also, please add the tool(s) you're using to play the ISO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

I used PowerISO to create a .DAA file of the CD-ROM, as well as mounting/playing it. 

The music, for now, is only playable if ripped and then burned on a CD-R.

Comment: AnyBurn did the trick, now PowerISO also shows a separate list of playable .CDA tracks. Weirdly, there's still no music inside the game. If the game's started off the .DAA, the in-game volume can't be turned up either. Could it be that the game can only use devices in Device Manager >  CD-ROM drives?

Comment: This question might be better asked in https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The software you use to mount the ISO needs to be written to handle proper CD read commands, like reading the audio. If it does not implement those commands then you will not hear the audio.

Comment: Okay, think I'm getting this. What I need to do, is to "burn" a virtual audio CD, with track 1 containing all data. IsoBuster extracted all six "tracks" as separate ISO's. Now it's just a question of how to make a virtual audio CD.